# import own module problem: no module named'xx'

Tags: python, module, importerror

I met troubles in importing my own modules. As you can see it said no module named guvBB, but I actually have guvBB.py. What is the problem? Thank you[image]

[image]

Comment: [**We don't allow images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow.**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please post all text as ([formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) text. Questions with images of text are routinely closed. Please also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure this & your future questions are suitable for this Q&A. **Also, Stack Overflow is an English-only site.**

Answer (score 1):

you have added the path on your system to the path on colab.
google doesnt have access to `c://.......`

go to table of content, find the folder,right click on it and put that path in your code `sys.path.append(newpath)`.